# Importance of the white cloth kept by Kevin's therapist

Tags: plot-explanation, split

In the movie split, a white cloth is shown which is kept by Kevin's therapist in between the door when she came to meet Kevin. The cloth is shown again near the climax scenes too. What does that mean? I couldn't find any connection and I am afraid I missed something relevant in this regard.

Comment: She shoves the napkin into the door jam so that the door will not click shut. She does this in order to keep the door from locking so she can escape.

Answer (score 10):

Dr Fletcher asks to use the bathroom, and discreetly stuffs a napkin in the lock of the door so she can't be locked in. That's the importance of the napkin.